# Качество ответов

Tags: обсуждение

Я не раз поднимал эту тему на "большом" СО, но, к сожалению, отклика она там не находила.

Я также не питаю особых иллюзий по поводу русскоязычного клона, но чисто для очистки совести я должен поднять этот вопрос.

Не секрет, что подобные сайты привлекают множество, мягко говоря, *неспециалистов*, которые, не обладая знаниями или опытом, тем не менее, стремятся поделиться своими соображениями по разнообразным вопросам. В итоге получается как в [не очень приличном анекдоте](http://phpfaq.ru/anecdotes#balls) - не знаешь, смеяться или плакать.

Пример: два ответа, авторы которых не имеют ни малейшего представления о том, о чем пытаются высказаться.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/443078/179379
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424900/179379

Автор первого попросту запутался, и весь его ответ построен вокруг одного заблуждения, не имеющего ничего общего с реальностью.

Второй автор представляет собой очень распространенный тип "слышал звон, да не знает где он" - ответ представляет собой взаимоисключающие параграфы, где приведённый код не защищает ни от одного типа атак, описанных во вводном предложении, подавая пример принципиально неверного подхода к выполнению запросов.

Как можно видеть на примере второго ответа, ни голосование (мой минус был нивелирован проходящим мимо таким же "знатоком"), ни установка флага (за несколько месяцев флаг так и не был обработан) не дают ни малейшего эффекта.

Вопрос. Что можно сделать для того, чтобы была возможность убирать с сайта хотя бы такой адов треш, не имеющий ни малейшего отношения к реальности?

Comment: Несчастные авторы этих ответов. Множеству новичков подобное сошло с рук, а этим достался весь гнев и минусы сообщества.

Comment: А почему вы никогда не заходите в чат? Там часто мелькает всякий ад, собранный со всего ресурса. По поводу тех двух вопросов, то да, они не очень. Все эти функции отправки запросов, привязанные к конкретной БД это просто кошмар ранних версий PHP.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Ничего

Треш был и будет. Единственный способ борьбы с ним - писать длинные развернутые заплюсованные ответы, чтобы никто никогда не смог до этого треша доскроллить. Ну и тактические бомбардировки минусами еще никто не отменял.

Лично я сегодя видел первый вопрос в очереди VLQ, и честно его пропустил. Просто потому, что я не захотел вникать в тонкости работы с данными в PHP.

## Что делать?

Постановка флагов не является штатным механизмом для решения таких проблем. Флаг уводит ответ в очередь VLQ. Вот один из постов в ней: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29814.

На выбор мне предлагается

- Выглядит нормально -  если ответ в порядке - ну точно нет!
- Правка - если вы можете исправить все проблемы этого ответа - не могу.
- Удалить - если данный ответ невозможно улучшить, и его следует удалить. хм, вроде вопрос про PHP, ответ про PHP, ни одна из причин в диалоге удаления не подходит (я знаю что это не причины удаления, а комменты, но все же...)
- Пропустить - если вы не уверены и хотите перейти к следующему вопросу - ну вот прямо мой случай!

Плохие вопросы надо минусовать. И писать в комментариях, почему именно они плохие - чтобы следующему было проще решиться нажать минус.

## Длинный развернутый ответ про неизбежность треша

Есть так называемая теория компетентности, которую часто рассказывают на всяких там agile трейнингах или семинарах про мотивацию:

[image: честно спертая картинка]

Копипаста к ней:

- Неосознанная некомпетентность.

  В состоянии неосознанной некомпетентности тебе неизвестно, что ты чего-то не знаешь. Возможно, есть смутные сомнения, что явно чего-то не хватает для полного счастья, но пока что они неосознаны.
- Осознанная некомпетентность.

  При осознанной некомпетентности ты осознаешь, что ты что-то конкретно не знаешь.
  Например, увидел, что кто-то ездит на велосипеде или крутит сальто и тебе захотелось то же самое.
- Осознанная компетентность.

  Стадия начала обучения. Допустим, обучаясь вождению автомобиля, человек пытается осознанно нажимать педали, переключать скорости, крутить руль, смотреть по сторонам. Учитывая, что в сознании человек может удержать от силы 5-7 объектов, а обычно и того меньше, то данная стадия с жизнью плохо совместима — человек постоянно совершает ошибки и перенапрягается.
- Неосознанная компетентность.

  Знания и умения стали привычками. Алгоритм действий заложен в бессознательное.
  Уже не надо задумываться, как водить машину, как писать письма, как разговаривать с людьми — все отработано до автоматизма.

Эта схема полностью применима к разработке ПО, и к ответам на Stack Overflow в частности.

Задающие вопрос находятся в стадии осознанной некомпетентности. Они точно знают что у них есть пробел в знании, и они стремятся его заполнить.

Отвечающие на вопрос могут находится на этой диаграмме где угодно:

- Неосознанная некомпетентность - он выдаст треш. Совершенно от всей души, из лучших побуждений, но - треш.
- Осознанная некомпетентность

  - Новичок - напишет ответ "у меня та же проблема"
  - Не новичок - промолчит.
- Осознанная компетентность - напишет нормальный ответ, с нормальным обоснованием.
- Неосознанная компетентность - напишет отличный ответ, но может пропустить обоснование или какие-то мелочи. Или пойдет ворчать в чат "почему нет нормальных вопросов".

Comment: Хорошая схема, спасибо что напомнили про нее )

Comment: "чтобы никто никогда не смог до этого треша доскроллить" - что характерно, два заминусованных ответа идут у меня почему-то первыми.

Comment: @insolor, зависит от установленного порядка сортировки, например по голосам, по дате ответа

Answer (score 4):

Ликвидировать плохие ответы на корню не получится — это вопрос человеческой психологии. Люди не любят серьёзно раздумывать, и любят простые, короткие (хоть и неправильные) ответы.

Но с такими ответами можно бороться. Если в какой-то области программирования на сайте есть критическая масса хороших специалистов (например, я могу сказать такое про тег [c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)), то рядом с каждым плохим ответом скорее всего появится хороший, длинный, обоснованный ответ специалиста, который заработает много плюсов.

Если же критической массы нет — нужны «подвижники», которые возьмут на себя труд обучить массу активных пользователей хорошими, длинными ответами, в которых терпеливо объясняется, что дважды два четыре, нет, не пять и не восемь, нет, в военное время тоже четыре, нет, ошибка в плавающей точке  третьего пентиума ни на что не влияет, нет, никаких «а может» или «а вот в двоичной системе». Уверенный ответ специалиста заработает плюсы, хотя и не сразу. Хорошие ответы рано или поздно привлекут в комьюнити специалистов, что позволит нарастить критическую массу.

Если таких просветителей по какому-то тегу не найдётся — этот тег не взлетит.

Answer (score -1):

Штатный механизм уже есть - установка флагов. Надо административно разобрать, почему он не срабатывает.

Comment: постановка флагов - не штатный механизм для решения таких проблем. штатный - минусование

Comment: @PashaPash но минусование может быть нивелировано набегом хомячков, а флаг, по идее, должен привести к появлению априорно компетентного модератора, который снесет балаган.

Comment: флаг помещает сообщение в очередь VLQ, которую разбирают обычные участники, и в которой нет подходящего для этого вопроса действия. и даже кнопки -1 нет в диалоге ревью. Хомячки же редко добегают дальше первых двух ответов. и вообще бояться жать +1 на посте с минусовым рейтингом.

Comment: дописал про флаг и проблему с ним в свой ответ

Comment: @PashaPash а повлиять на механизмы работы флага нельзя? чтобы запускался процесс коллегиального удаления, как с закрытием вопросов?

Comment: @gbg, априорно компетентный модератор не может быть компетентен абсолютно во всем.

Comment: @gbg скорее всего можно (но только для всех сайтов SO). флаги предназначены для неисправимых проблем с качеством в смысле общего содержания ответа (например, ответ-ссылка - заслуживает флага). а не в смысле "обоснованности, истинности, полезности для других".

Comment: Модератор априорно компетентен только в модерации, но не по теме каждой метки.

Comment: @NickVolynkin идея как раз состоит в том, что поставивший флаг приведет состоятельные аргументы. Тогда модератору только останется убедиться в их весомости.