# Голосование по изменению тематики сайта

Tags: обсуждение, тематика, голосование

Каждый ответ на этот вопрос - **конкретное предложение** по изменению тематики и связанных с ней правил сайта. В ответе содержатся:

- **Само предложение:** Что и как предлагается изменить.
- **Аргументы "за":** Почему предложенные изменения нужны сайту и сообществу.
- **Аргументы "против":** Какой вред может нанести сайту и сообществу реализация данного предложения? Есть ли способы, тем не менее, реализовать предложенное, минимизировав этот вред? Если да, то какие?

Голосуя **за** ответ вы **поддерживаете** соответственное предложение, **против** - **отклоняете**.

Все ответы общие, если у вас есть собственные аргументы за или против предложения, отличные от уже изложенных, - пожалуйста, добавьте их в ответ.

#### Темы голосования

- [Разрешить тематику SuperUser на ruSO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2776)
- [Разрешить тематику Hardware на ruSO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2777)
- [Разрешить вопросы по поиску программ, библиотек и тематической литературы на ruSO, при условии соответствия их указанным критериям](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2778)
- [Повысить требования к качеству вопросов по программированию на ruSO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2779)
- [Разрешить вопросы, сформулированные как техническое задание и предполагающие ответом цельное решение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2795/181472)

Comment: На мой взгляд хорошее описание критериев оценки вопросов есть [по одной](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/234/6) из приведенных вами ссылок.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky вроде и хорошо, но тот же вопрос про зловреда в браузере не отвечает, строго говоря, первому и третьему критерию, однако вполне может быть полезен программисту не аникейщику. Да, с большей вероятностью такие вопросы задают вообще не программисты, но личность спрашивающего не должна играть роли, при оценке вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

#### Предлагаю

Cчитать тематическими вопросы по поиску библиотек, литературы и программного обеспечения, отвечающие следующим критериям:

- **Область поиска:** В вопросе явно и чётко указано, какие требования выдвигаются автором к объекту поиска, во избежание получения заведомо ошибочных рекомендаций.
- **Область применения:** В вопросе указано, какая задача побудила автора искать новый инструмент или литературу. Это должно помочу участникам определиться с рекомендациями и не советовать лишнего.
- **Обоснование необходимости:** Данные вопросы, не взирая на всю их потенциальную пользу, не являются профильными для сообщества ruSO. Вопрос должен содержать пояснение, где уже искал автор, какие варианты его не устроили и почему. Сообщество должно видеть, что спрашивающий действительно в затруднительном положении, а не просто поленился сходить в Гугл.
- **Соответствие тематике:** Здесь не ищут книги по вышиванию, или замену Ворду. Только тематическая литература и техническое ПО, только хардкор!

#### Аргументы "За"

- Текущее решение со списками литературы прекрасно решает проблему поиска книги по определённому языку/тематике, но не способно дать ответ на более конкретные и, как результат, более качественные вопросы, например, "Подскажите литературу и онлайн ресурсы по использованию языка R в специфике исследования генома?" (Я не с потолка взял вопрос, это одно из наиболее частых применений данного языка в научной деятельности).
- Ответы на подобные вопросы крайне полезны участникам, которые, в силу сжатых временных рамок, не имеют возможности подобрать подходящую книгу, библиотеку или софт методом проб и ошибок.

#### Аргументы "Против":

- Подобная вольница может вылиться в кучу вопросов, типа "В каком блокноте есть подсветка Python?", однако наличие чётких требований и следящих за их исполнением участников не должно дать этой проблеме всерьёз навредить сообществу. К сожалению, изложенные выше требования четкими не являются:

  - Область поиска и область применения - каждый, кто задает вопрос, считает что достаточно четко определил область. "Книга по C# для новичков" - явное и четкое определение.
  - Обоснование необходимости - "гуглил, не нашел ничего подходящего, нужно чтобы сдать лабы по алгоритмам". Опять же, сам по себе факт задания вопроса показывает необходимость. Иначе бы топикастер его просто не задал. "Действительно затруднительное положение" - **чисто субъективная** оценка и не может быть в таков виде включена в правила, т.к. подразумевает закрытие вопросов формулировкой "ваше положение не слишком затруднительно, оффтопик!"
- Ответы на подобные вопросы обычно сводятся к ссылке или к неподдерживаемому списку.
- Ответы на подобные вопросы быстро устаревают. Время их жизни - полгода максимум. После этого они начинают вести пользователей на неактулальное старье. То, что не неактуальный ответ будет помечен неснимаемой зеленой галкой - только усугубит положение.

  - Вчера эта библиотека была хорошей, сегодня - она заброшена и не поддерживается.
  - Вчера книга была популярной, сегодня - в ней 80% информации неактуальны.
  - Сегодня в моде Knockout, завтра - Angular.

Comment: Все такие вопросы тематические (и независимо от времени проведенном в гугле)

Comment: Как предполагается оценивать обоснование необходимости? Банальное "Гуглил, не помогло" попадает под описанное выше (т.е. не поленился + задал вопрос, значит действительно есть необходимость)

Comment: "Подскажите хорошую книгу по C# для новичка. нужно выучить за неделю - хочу сдать сессию, надо написать 20 лаб по алгоритмам. гуглил - не помогло, все советуют разное.  желательно что-то меньше 100 страниц (в существующем списке ничего меньше 300 нет), для студентов-гуманитариев" - готово, онтопичный вопрос :)

Comment: Предыдущие обсуждения: [про библиотеки](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2615/6), [про литературу](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2009).

Answer (score -3):

#### Предлагаю

- Официально расширить тематику ruSO, включив в неё **вопросы по работе с оборудованием (Hardware)**.
- Во избежание массового появления на сайте низкокачественных вопросов по данной тематике и черезмерного расширения спектра вопросов, ввести следующие критерии некачественных и нетематических вопросов:

  - Вопросы, для получения ответа на которые следует обратиться на сайт разработчика аппаратного обеспечения или в спецификацию. Отвечающим на такие вопросы, фактически, придётся сделать то, что поленился сделать автор ("Какая температура считается критической для процессора XXX?").
  - Вопросы по работе с оборудованием, ответы на которые заведомо есть в инструкции к оборудованию ("Как поставить мелодию на iPhone").
  - Вопросы по работе с оборудованием или проектированию оборудования, не имеющего отношения к пользовательской или серверной вычислительной технике (электроника, робототехника, вот это всё), кроме вопросов по программированию прошивок.
  - Вопросы по некорректной работе оборудования, однозначный ответ на которые не может быть дан на основании словесного описания проблемы (программиста можно попросить показать код, а хардварщика? "Принесите ваш сервер на дом к отвечающему"?)

#### Аргументы "За"

- Это неожиданно, но второй рабочий инструмент программиста, после головы, - вычислительная машина. Строго говоря, программисту даже **важнее** получить быстрый и качественный ответ по проблемам с железом, чем какому-нибудь ученику 5-го "А", сжёгшему свою видеокарту трёхсуточным заплывом в Perfect World.
- Затруднительно писать качественные программы на технике, в архитектуре которой ни черта не смыслишь. Поэтому появляются [такие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/505310/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9) вопросы. Они, вроде, и про железо, но плох тот программист, который сочтёт ответ на подобный вопрос не нужным.
- Как в предыдущем случае, переадресовать такие вопросы некуда, так как портал Hardware работает только на английском языке.

#### Аргументы "Против"

- Всё те же опасения наплыва низкокачественных вопросов про неработающие Айфоны. Ограничения - как раз про них.
- Расширение тематики на аппаратное обеспечение приведёт на сайт и специалистов **исключительно** по железу. У этих людей могут возникнуть вопросы вроде "А почему ПК и серверы обсуждать можно, а дронов и интеллектуальные камеры видеонаблюдения - нет?". Потому я вынужден предложить заранее и явно запретить расширение тематики на вопросы, не имеющие прямой связи с IT-индустрией.

Comment: А чем проектирование оборудования не угодило?

Comment: @Qwertiy не всё, а только не ВТ. Смотрите второй аргумент "против".

Comment: Ладно, с тематикой конкретнее можно будет потом разобраться.

Answer (score -6):

#### Предлагаю

- Официально расширить тематику ruSO, включив в неё **вопросы пользователей по использованию программного обеспечения (SU)**
- Во избежание массового появления на сайте низкокачественных вопросов по данной тематике, ввести следующие критерии некачественных вопросов:

  - Вопросы по работе с ПО, ответы на которые можно легко получить из встроенной справки или просто методом тыка, но не вопросы, ответ на которые подразумевает неочевидную последовательность действий.
    **Плохие вопросы:** "Как сделать текст в Ворде жирным?", "Как создать слой в Фотошопе?".
    **Хорошие вопросы:** "Как напечатать символ Юникода, код которого известен, если редактор не поддерживает HTML?", "Как изменить цвет ячейки в Excel по условию?", "Как организовать сортировку по нескольким признакам в Word?".
  - Вопросы, для получения ответа на которые следует обратиться на сайт разработчика программного обеспечения или в спецификацию. Отвечающим на такие вопросы, фактически, придётся сделать то, что поленился сделать автор ("Какой предел числа полигонов модели в Wings3d?").
  - Вопросы, для получения ответа на которые достаточно воспользоваться любым поисковиком и ткнуть по первой-второй ссылке ("Что это за программа?").

#### Аргументы "За"

- Программист - тоже юзер. Умение писать код не делает его, автоматически, специалистом по безопасности, способным выловить [любой вредонос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/322740/14756) с помощью консоли и такой-то матери, не поможет вылечить [баг в проприетарном приложении](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27803/why-does-my-character-walk-forward-automatically), или освоить многофунциональную IDE, которую он в первый раз видит. Грамотные вопросы и ответы по данной тематике потенциально полезны членам сообщества.
- Мы, в отличии от enSO, не можем отправлять людей с данными вопросами на SuperUser, так как указанный сайт представлен только на английском языке и [вряд ли](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/225/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D0%9E-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0-stack-overflow-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81?rq=1#comment436_234) будет переведён.

#### Аргументы "Против"

- Как показывает опыт БитКода, качество вопросов по тематике SU в целом ниже, чем по программированию. Ограничения, призванные решить эту проблему, предложены выше, но, возможно, кто-то сочтёт их недостаточными.

Comment: Я плюсанул бы, если убрать все эти крайне субъективные критерии некачественных ответов.

Comment: @avp предложите объективные. Если я уберу ограничения - вы плюсанёте, да. Вы **один**.

Comment: я уже несколько дней разными словами пытаюсь Вам втолковать, что это **невозможно** (у каждого свои критерии). Значит не нужны никакие. Идея простая -- не нравится, не отвечайте (проходите мимо). (далее, надеюсь, последует шаг 2 -- неплюсованные и без принятых или плюсованных ответов темы *автоматически удаляются* (скажем, через полгода))

Comment: "освоить многофунциональную IDE" - это уже онтопик, вопрос об использовании инструментов для программирования или администрирования.

Answer (score -7):

#### Предлагаю

Вывести из тематики ruSO следующие вопросы по программированию, как низкокачественные:

- Вопросы с кодом, синтаксис которого заведомо неверен. Здесь имеется в виду, не отдельная синтаксическая ошибка, даже повторённая многократно, а полностью нерабочий код, исправить который не переписывая его с нуля (а порой - и просто понять) невозможно.
- Вопросы, сводящиеся к внесению косметических изменений в элементарные учебные примеры кода.
- Вопросы, по внесению изменений в чужой код ("Как сделать, чтобы эта программа делала не то, а вон то?").

#### Аргументы "За"

- Ответы на такие вопросы бесполезны другим участникам сообщества, так как помогают решить только конкретную задачу, стоящую перед конкретным участником.
- Попытка, тем не менее, дать на такие вопросы полный и полезный сообществу ответ выльется в фактическое написание отвечающим главы из учебника, которую должен был прочитать спрашивающий. Задавать такие вопросы явно не рекомендуется справкой.
- Попытка дать краткий, но обстоятельный ответ, вынудит отвечающего привести ссылку на сторонний ресурс, вместо ответа на сайте, что так же
  не рекомендуется.
- Ответы на подобные вопросы сомнительны с моральной точки зрения, так как побуждают спрашивающих пользоваться готовыми рецептами, вместо изучения хотя бы фундаментальных основ предмета.

#### Аргументы "Против"

- Любой язык изучается в основном на тривиальных примерах путем внесения в них небольших, косметических, изменений. Практически, предлагается запретить задавать вопросы, появляющиеся в процессе изучения основ любого языка.
- Вопросы на SO задаются ради получения ответа. Тот факт, что ответ решит только конкретную задачу, стоящую перед конкретным участником - не может использоваться в качестве причины закрытия. По сути, такая формулировка подразумевает закрытие вопросов с причиной "(я считаю что) точно такой же вопрос больше ни у кого не возникнет". Под нее попадает 90% существующих вопросов по SO.
- Вопросы с кодом, синтаксис которого заведомо неверен, и которые невозможно понять, на данный момент подлежат закрытию как низкокачественные, т.е. и так явлются оффтопиком. Этот пункт по сути ничего не меняет.
- Понятие "косметических" изменений сугубо субъективно. "Как сделать чтобы текст был красным на языке X" - обычный вопрос по основам технологии, такие вопросы составляют основу SO, и запрет их - это, практически, превращение SO в закрытый клуб по интересам. Задающие такие вопросы, по сути, находятся на стадии [неосознанной некомпетентности](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1346/177221) - той самой стадии, из которой сложнее всего продвинуться дальше. Запретить подобные вопросы - значит сделать ruSO **полностью бесполезным** для тех, кто только осваивает технологию.
- Подобная политика может отпугнуть новичков от пользования сайтом.
- В предложении "запретить" не приведено *ни одного конкретного вопроса* (в виде ссылки, а не в виде взятого из головы примера про красный текст в PHP), который на данный момент считается онотопиком, и который предлагается сделать оффтопиком. По сути, предлагается увести в оффтопик неопределенный круг вопросов с размытыми критериями и формулировкой.
- Коротко - суть предложения предложения сводится к "Я не хочу видеть на SO вопросов от новичков. Пусть сидят, читают книги, гуглят, делают туториалы, и не задают вопросов в той области, в которой ничего не понимают. А когда разберутся - пусть приходят к нам и задают хорошие интересные вопросы".

Comment: На сколько я понимаю, подобные вопросы и сейчас выходят за рамки сайта. Пожалуйста, подскажите, чем данное предложение отличается от двух причин закрытия вопросов в разделе «не по теме»?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky в чате **модератор** считает, что это - вопросы от новичков, которые закрывать нельзя. Если текущие правила говорят эти вопросы закрыть, то тогда что за бардак на сайте с их трактовкой? Лично я согласен, что, фактически, данные вопросы **уже** запрещены, только активная часть сообщества не желает этого признавать. Фактически, данное предложение, это не изменение, а трактовка правил.

Answer (score -10):

**Предлагаю:**

- Разрешить вопросы типа "Вот моя задача (или маленькое ТЗ), я еще сам не думал, но решил здесь спросить, как можно было бы подходить к ее решению".
- Или даже вопросы типа "Сделайте все за меня"

[В справке / как задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) написано:

> Домашние задания надо выполнять самостоятельно. Если у вас возник
>   вопрос по домашнему заданию, не просите его сделать за вас. Задайте
>   конкретный вопрос о проблеме, которую вы не можете решить.
>   Программирование — это то, в чём надо разбираться самому, либо не
>   заниматься им вовсе. Если для вас программирование — лишний предмет в
>   учебной программе, есть сайты и люди на этих сайтах, выполняющие
>   задания за материальное вознаграждение. Здесь предлагать выполнить
>   работу за вас и наоборот — моветон.

Именно вопреки этому пункту и можно бы было сделать изменение, если это стоит того. Если получится, то не касательно домашних работ, а касательно начинаний.

**При этом необходимо:**

- Четкая постановка задачи
- как-то все-таки регламентировать ее масштаб, чтобы не было такого "Подробное описание реализации собственной операционной системы"
- какая-то категоризация, возможно. ... Надо продумать...
- ну и требовать, чтобы были указаны технические ограничения, например, "язык такой-то", "десктоп", "БД такая-то"
- если получится, то мотивировать людей больше помогать добрым начинаниям, чем чему-нибудь бесполезному.
- Ну тогда, сделать домашнюю работу за другого - чаще недоброе начинание - надо продумать этот момент ...
- Необходимо продумать критерии и ограничения на заголовок таких вопросов, чтобы от них в будущем была польза

---

**Аргументы ЗА:**

- Для тех, кто отвечает, такие задачи могут показаться более творческими и интересными.
- Думаю, что на конкретный технический вопрос конкретного языка знает ответ меньше человек, чем на более общий вопрос, например, "планирую сделать сайт для того-то, поделитесь вашими планчиками или проэктиками по реализации моей идеи". То есть, можно охватить сегмент энтузиастов, которые подкованы  архитектурно, нежели чем практически в деталях.
- Кому-то это может оказать реальную помощь
- Среднему программисту со средним опытом ответ на такой его вопрос может помочь какую-то деталь или часть сделать более оптимальным образом, чем если бы он сам делал.
- Начинающему это это может дать импульс к обучению и более быстрому завершению задачи
- Если ответов несколько, то на стартапе задачи можно получить разные направления решения задачи
- ruSO становится более интересным, для того, чтобы следить за новыми вопросами, ответами на них, то есть для обучения. (В случае, если был задан интересный вопрос)
- Если какое-то решение реально хорошее, то на него, возможно, будут больше ссылаться, что, как мне кажется хорошо для сайта
- Может быть интересной комбинация такого вопроса с bounty - вознаграждением

**Аргументы Против:**

- Возможно, что ответ не поможет вопрошающему по причине намного более высокого уровня знаний отвечающего (или, наоборот, более низкого)
- Такие ответы занимают больше времени, поэтому, возможно, будет много не отвеченных
- возможно, сложнее содержать сайт в чистоте
- Сложно подобрать правила, что можно задавать, что нельзя. Собственно, и сам вопрос задать сложно. Потом может быть много обиды у вопрошающего, что вот я все хорошо спросил, меня просто не поняли. И действительно как тут опишешь критерии, правила. Дело нечеткое. С новичками тоже сложно. С одной стороны - не отвратить, с другой сказать, что надо не так, а так. Хотя, может быть, отвратить - не самое страшное
- Может быть море комментариев, обсуждений
- Изменились требования... Что тогда..? Если пытаться поправить текущий вопрос, то много неаккуратностей, а если новый задавать, то что теперь, по новой решать задачу?
- нет объективного критерия правильности, то есть куда галочку ставить, но это вроде бы не важно
- Если даже есть крутой ответ, то он может затеряться. В дальнейшем, кто-то может попытаться спросить подобный вопрос, но не найти уже существующий, т.к. сложно подобрать ключевые слова
- может быть наоборот, вопрос с названием "Разработка сайта". Другой человек хочет задать вопрос с таким же заголовком, но по сути эти вопросы могут быть совсем разными
- Совсем теоретически ruSO может прослыть у студентов или ленивцев как вероятность привахтоваться в бухте халявы
- Ответ на такой вопрос может быть развернутым, как статья. Если представить вопрос размером со статью, потом 5 ответов, каждый размером со статью, то читать будет не удобно. Думаю, SO предполагался изначально для более мелких масштабов, хотя не уверен
- Как-то может быть не справедливо, если что кто-то спрашивает короткий вопрос, далее бедняга энтузиаст в течение недели решает проблему, а деньги за работу получает тот, кто спросил
- Если у какого-то энтузиаста есть своя работа, но так же есть страстишка или слабость отвлекаться, то он возьмется решать чужие задачи, оставив свои и его уволят с работы

---

PS: Я все еще новичок на сайте, не знаю всех тонкостей, так что прошу прощения, если чего не так.

Comment: Ну, автором может и нет, но в вопросе этого явно не описано. Но чтобы можно было полноценно обсуждать и дополнять это предложение, его как минимум стоило сделать общим, как остальные.

Comment: @D-side все варианты публикуются одновременно (насколько это вообще возможно), и новых **на третий день голосования** добавлять нельзя.

Comment: @Risto поскольку каждое предложение самодостаточно, нет разницы, когда оно опубликовано, голосование за/против каждого из них независимо. Можно было опубликовать отдельным вопросом. Можно было все варианты так опубликовать. Но зачем? Это ж не выбор варианта, это рассмотрение каждого.

Comment: @D-side вы предлагаете модераторам закрепить тему голосования в важном **навечно**? И как тогда считать результаты? Нет, бюллетень голосования формируется один раз.

Comment: @Risto, предложение вполне имеет право на жизнь.

Comment: @Risto даже если он будет убран из важного, он какое-то время ещё повисит в верхах Меты., получит свою долю минусов и в конечном счёте всё равно будет отклонён. :) Или, существенно модифицированный, перекочует в собственный вопрос, где будет сообществом доработан, хотя я не очень в это верю.

Comment: Уж не знаю чем продиктовано желание, расширить онтопик в эту сторону, но это точно плохая идея. Прям очень-очень плохая. Ничего кроме оттока экспертов и притока халявщиков ожидать от таких изменений не приходится

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, да но не в рамках этого поста. Вы в бюллетень тоже кандидатов предлагаете вписывать задним числом? Опять же, человек примазывается к **моему** начинанию с предложением, с которым я **категорически не согласен**. А припоминать его художества будут **мне**. Пусть собирает свои минусы в другом топике.

Comment: @Risto, расслабьтесь, мета это про сообщество, а не лично про вас. Данное предложение относится к сути дела, озвученного в вопросе. Кто автор - не имеет значения. Когда предложение добавлено (если это сделано **до** окончания голосования) тоже не имеет значения. Поймите -- мы выбираем не победителя, а голосуем по каждому конкретному вопросу в отдельности.

Comment: Вот... теперь по, собственно, предложению. Если посмотреть на подсказку, всплывающую при наведении на стрелку вниз, видно очень много общих черт. "Данный вопрос не отражает стремления разобраться; он непонятен или несёт пользы". На фоне этого предложение выглядит примерно следующим образом: "Давайте сделаем вопросы, которые вусмерть заминусуют, онтопиком?" Действия тут не требуются. Во многих случаях **они и так в рамках тематики**, у них другие проблемы: в них обычно **не хватает деталей** или **у автора нет необходимых знаний, чтобы понять решение**.

Comment: @Risto, не знал, что это голосование лично ваше. Чего-то мне показалось, что задал вопрос кто-то другой и только вы чего-то отвечали. Прошу прощения если что-то не корректно, но я сказал, что новичок. D-side говорит, что ничего страшного в том, что написал это, как предложение, так что пока не стираю.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev: Продиктовано это предложение тем, что сам я скорее теоретик нежели чем практик. По складу ума мне скорее интересно участвовать в архитектурных вопросах, чем детальных технических (если вообще найдется время участвовать). Поэтому и написал предложение. Имел ввиду, что в вопросе задача д.б. поставлена четко. Мне кажется, что есть сегмент возможных хороших, интересных вопросов, но на которые сейчас скажут "звучит как ТЗ, -1". Хотя, что на практике получится, мне предусмотреть сложно.

Comment: @AndreyK., нету таких вопросов. Если ваше предложение примут, вместо ru.SO мы получим бесплатную фриланс биржу. Лично я -- против.

Comment: @Risto Что значит новые ответы не предполагаются? Голосование открытое, предложения принимаются от всех участников.

Comment: @AndreyK посмотрите http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/231/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0