# Обсуждаемое на мете и историческая блокировка

Tags: дефект, блок-важных-вопросов

В блоке обсуждаемое на мете показывается вопрос 
[Голосование по изменению тематики сайта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2775/178988), 
на котором уже 3 дня висит историческая блокировка.

Нелогично :)

Comment: Свежо предание, а верится с трудом.

Comment: Однако ж как долгоиграющи последствия одной драмы в чате)

Comment: Эээ.. А минус-то за что??

Comment: @ЮрийСПб teh drama!

Comment: @NickVolynkin, снова выползло...

Comment: @Qwertiy не вижу. Ссылку можно?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ссылку на что? Держи скриншот: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kFmY2.png

Comment: О боги, топик ненависти! Что это было?

Comment: @Discord, решил всю мету перечитать? Там же даже один ответ в ноль вышел :)